# tensorflow 1.5 ImportError: No module named tensorflow.python.client

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to run a simple python script that uses Tensorflow to print the available GPU devices. The script is

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

def get_available_gpus():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == 'GPU']

get_available_gpus()
```

I have the following related modules installed:

```
pip show tensorflow-gpu
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 1.5.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: wheel, six, tensorflow-tensorboard, numpy, absl-py, protobuf
```

However, when I run the script I get the following error:

```
python get_available_gpus.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_available_gpus.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
ImportError: No module named tensorflow.python.client
```